# old American car started stalling on idle after long maintenance in a shop. What could be the causes?

Tags: fuel-system, stall, idle, buick, lesabre

Early 90s Buick, car has not stalled in a long time. After extensive maintenance which fixed injection issues, suddenly acquired distinct stalling on idle behavior. Starts ok in traffic, but still quite scary.

ICV is new, mechanics mentioned that EGR valve is semi-clogged.

What should I look into? V6 distributorless injector engine SFI (multi-port sequential).

ICV being idle control valve, Buick being LeSabre.

EDIT: it appears, aside simply stalling on idle, it also chokes when starting to move off idle, as if there's  amajor fuel shortage. I can only REV it through to be able to move forward when this happens.

Changing the pump, air and fuel filters has not altered this behavior.

Comment: Welcome to the forum.  I will say, on this (and each and every forum within StackOverflow... ) its often best to describe all abbreviations When First Used (WFU).. Okay to use them, please help us all (and the newcomers to the site) understand exactly what you are talking about.  I have no idea what is an ICV? I know what an EGR is, but I doubt all the newcomers will know.  Additionally for the 90's there were LOTS of changes to fuel systems that are super dependent on specific model year.  Exactly what year in the 90's are we talking about ?  (Year, make and model?)  Many thx

Comment: Is it idling at low revs?

Comment: yes, quite quiet, as a matter of fact

Comment: FI system is SFI (also added into description)

Comment: Worn out fuel pump? Measured fuel pressure? Replaced fuel filter?

Comment: Fuel filter and pump just got replaced.

Comment: Have you checked the air filter?  Sometimes a mouse can build a nest when the vehicle sits for a while which just plugs the air filter of course.  I'd also check for vacuum leaks as idle has the highest vacuum and will shut down an engine at idle that runs good at any other RPM.  I believe the EGR is also supposed to close at idle to keep from killing the engine and that's another possibility if it's semi-clogged.  Sometimes you can clean it out with a screwdriver to get a lot of the coking off and make it function a bit longer.